# Make php do_action conditional upon class field

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry a noob question. I wish to make this:

```
<?php  do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails'); ?>
```

Conditional to a custom field called 360 with the value yes.

```
<?php // do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails'); // ?>
```

For the simple reason that my plugin uses 36 images to create a rotating display. 
When I dont use the plugin, I want to use the thumbnails. Many thanks Asa.

I have tried

```
<?php 

 if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', false)) { 
 do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails'); 
 } else { 
 do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails'); 
 } 
 ?>
```

But I still get to see the thumbnails when 360 is returned as false?

I have tried

```
<?php 

 if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true)) { 
 // do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails');
 } else { 
 do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails'); 
 } 
 ?>
```

Works! Many thanks.

Comment: "Conditional to a custom field called 360 with the value yes." I have absolutely no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean - if there is a value for the custom meta value of 360 (ie you'd created a custom metabox with a checkbox with id 360 in it) for that page/post then the product thumbnails are used.  If not then you put in your rotating display.

```
<?php

 if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true)) {
     do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails');
 } else {
    // your rotating display code.
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: I have tried, but still get thumbnails with 360 even when set to false.

Comment: Aha, nice one - this link from the wordpress stack exchange site is also useful for using custom checkboxes - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/retrieve-meta-key-when-checkbox-is-used